# Use Nokogiri::XML#collect_namespaces or #namespaces?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I found that Nokogiri::XML has two methods to get a list of namespaces: `#namespaces` and `collect_namespaces`:

```
doc.namespaces
{
                 "xmlns:iso4217" => "http://www.xbrl.org/2003/iso4217",
                    "xmlns:link" => "http://www.xbrl.org/2003/linkbase",
    "xmlns:tdnet-qcedjpsm-99970" => "http://www.xbrl.tdnet.info/jp/br/tdnet/qc/edjp/sm/99970/2013-08-02399970",
                "xmlns:tse-t-ed" => "http://www.xbrl.tdnet.info/jp/br/tdnet/t/ed/2007-06-30",
                "xmlns:tse-t-hi" => "http://www.xbrl.tdnet.info/jp/br/tdnet/t/hi/2007-06-30",
                   "xmlns:xlink" => "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink",
                     "xmlns:xsd" => "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema",
                     "xmlns:xsi" => "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",
                   "xmlns:xbrli" => "http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance"
}
doc.collect_namespaces
{
                   "xmlns:xbrli" => "http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance",
                     "xmlns:xsi" => "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",
                     "xmlns:xsd" => "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema",
                   "xmlns:xlink" => "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink",
                "xmlns:tse-t-hi" => "http://www.xbrl.tdnet.info/jp/br/tdnet/t/hi/2007-06-30",
                "xmlns:tse-t-ed" => "http://www.xbrl.tdnet.info/jp/br/tdnet/t/ed/2007-06-30",
    "xmlns:tdnet-qcedjpsm-99970" => "http://www.xbrl.tdnet.info/jp/br/tdnet/qc/edjp/sm/99970/2013-08-02399970",
                    "xmlns:link" => "http://www.xbrl.org/2003/linkbase",
                 "xmlns:iso4217" => "http://www.xbrl.org/2003/iso4217"
```

Both methods works almost the same except one returns the inverse order of the hash.  Is there a reason for this?

I couldn't get information which method should I use.

If there there is no difference except for order, I'll use `namespaces`, because it's shorter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`collect_namespaces` gets all namespaces from `Document`. `namespaces` gets the namespaces in effect on a `Node`.

```
d = Nokogiri::XML(<<XML)
  <a xmlns:a="http://example.com/a">
    <b xmlns:b="http://example.com/b">
    </b>
  </a>
XML

d.namespaces
# => {"xmlns:a"=>"http://example.com/a"}
# because `xmlns:b` is below the root, it is not in effect

d.collect_namespaces
# => {"xmlns:a"=>"http://example.com/a", "xmlns:b"=>"http://example.com/b"}
# gets everything

d.at_css('b').namespaces
# => {"xmlns:b"=>"http://example.com/b", "xmlns:a"=>"http://example.com/a"}
# on the child, both namespaces are in effect

d.at_css('b').collect_namespaces
# => NoMethodError
# because `collect_namespaces` only works on `Document`
```